# Firebase Functions and external node packages

Tags: javascript, firebase, jwt, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

In **./functions/index.js** I have required a couple of external packages (node_modules) like: jsonwebtoken, uuid or escapeHtml but they do not work as **in the browser** I get:

> "Error: could not handle the request"

**questions: how can I make it work?**

./functions/index.js:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

exports.getToken = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const token = await jwt.sign({ id: 3333 }, "secret");
  response.send("Hello from Firebase! + ", token);
});
```

PS: In the documentations it says it's suppose to allow external packages even local packages
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "uuid": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: If the error is happening in the browser, then edit the question to show the browser code and the specific line of code where it's failing.  What you're showing is just the Cloud Function code, which runs entirely on the backend and does not involve the browser in any way.  The browser code will just invoke this function and receive the response.

Comment: Hi Doug, as it is shown in the code, the browser is supposed to display "Hello from Firebase + a generated token", but what it appears on the "/" is "Error: could not handle the request".

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're observing.  As I said, edit the question to show the browser code.  We need to be able to see everything you're doing.

Comment: can you share your `package.json`

Comment: @DougStevenson by browser code you mean what code is rendered in the browser (via View Page Source) ?

Comment: Your question should include enough information that anyone can reproduce the results.

Comment: @Reza I have added the package.json code right now

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't know what else information to give you :(

Comment: Show the code that invokes this function, and be clear about what you expect it to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson this is a onRequest function that is not called by any code from my side as it was with an onCall functions. It's a function that gets triggered when opening mysite/getToken and should render the result in the browser

Comment: That's not the way onRequest functions work.  They must be invoked by some other calling code.  There is nothing automatic about them, and they don't directly render code in the browser.

Comment: @DougStevenson It's not true, you can see in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies#javascript

Comment: Yes, I know Cloud Functions very well.  You need to write code to invoke the function and handle the response.

Comment: @DougStevenson are you saying referring to this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#web_2 ?

Comment: No, I'm talking about onRequest.  They require client code just like callables.

Comment: @DougStevenson could you show me an example? i'm not sure I understand what you have in mind :(

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the http://console.firebase.google.com dashboard I found out that in the **functions/logs** there is this error:

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

I think this means that with a free firebase account (Spark) it will not allow me to run external node_packages. But probably this would work with a Pay as you go plan (Blaze).

Can someone with a Blaze plan please confirm that external node packages work with firebase in their `functions/index.js` file?